# How to add if-else in react js component?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function. Here I want to set the values for the variables head and edit like :

```
if (head==='Save'){head: 'Edit',edit: 'false'}
```

How do I add if-else in the following function?

```
editItem: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({     
    head: 'Save',
    edit: 'true'          
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
editItem: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.state.head === 'Save') {
        this.setState({
            head: 'Edit',
            edit: 'false',
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            head: 'Save',
            edit: 'true'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less verbose, maybe at the expense of readability:

```
editItem: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newState=this.state.head === 'Save'?{head: 'Edit',edit: 'false'}:{head: 'Save',edit: 'true'};
  this.setState(newState);
}
```